# Mirth Traverse through a GlobalMap

Tags: mirth

In my mirth implementation (Mirth Connect Server 2.2.1) I have a GlobalMap that contains keys and properties comes from external property file. How do I get the key set from the Globalmap and iterate it to get the values?

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate through the global map like so:

```
for each (key in globalMap.getVariables().keySet().toArray())
    logger.info(key+': '+$g('key'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly how you're initializing your key/value set, but here's a basic rundown of what I do.

To stick a key/value set in the GlobalMap:

```
//I will assume that you have your own routine for initializing the
//kv set from your property file
var kvPairs = {'key1':'value1',
                     'key2':'value2',
                     'key3':'value3'};

globalMap.put('keyValuePairs',kvPairs);
```

To extract the set from the GlobalMap:

```
// Method 1
// Grab directly from GlobalMap object.
var kvPairs = globalMap.get('keyValuePairs');


// Method 2
// Use the Mirth shorthand to search all map objects until the
// desired variable is located.
var kvPairs = $('keyValuePairs');
```

To iterate through the set:

```
// Method 1
// If you need to access both the keys and the associated values, then
// use a for in loop
for (var key in kvPairs)
{
    var value = kvPairs[key];

    // you now have key and value, and can use them as you see fit
}


// Method 2
// If you only need the values, and don't need the keys, then you can use
// the more familiar for each in loop
for each (var value in kvPairs)
{
    // you now have value, and can use it as you see fit;
}
```